# $\log_{10}[\frac1{2^x+x-1}]=x[\log_{10}5-1]$

Tags: logarithms

> If $\log_{10}[\frac1{2^x+x-1}]=x[\log_{10}5-1],$ then $x =$

I liked this question. Therefore, submitting it as Q&A format.

Comment: This is just computation...

Comment: I agree with Kezer.

Answer (score 1):

$$-\log_{10}(2^x+x-1)=x\log_{10}5-x$$
$$\log_{10}(2^x+x-1)=x-\log_{10}5^x$$
$$2^x+x-1=10^{x-\log_{10}5^x}$$
$$2^x+x-1=\frac{10^{x}}{10^{\log_{10}5^x}}$$
$$2^x+x-1=\frac{10^{x}}{5^x}$$
$$2^x+x-1=2^x$$

Therefore, $x=1$.

Comment: That's the only meaningful answer. (+1)